# What is the correct opposite of fan?

Tags: grammar, antonyms

Is it correct to say or write "Its sad to see how fast people become fan and critic"?

Actually I want to express my feelings about the people of current age who will be your fans but soon they will become your opponents and they will say bad things about you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Critic* can be used that way, but juxtaposed with *fan* (and hence the context of reviews), it might not be easy to distinguish between the 'unfavourable opinion' sense and the 'professional judge of art' sense when you hold both terms on equal footing with the phrase "fan and critic".

> **critic** *noun*
>   1 A person who expresses an unfavourable opinion of something.
>   ‘critics of the new legislation say it is too broad’
>   2 A person who judges the merits of literary or artistic works, especially one who does so professionally.
>   ‘a theatre critic’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/critic)

You can weight the interpretation more heavily towards the 'unfavourable opinion' sense by noting the process of change, juxtaposed with the word 'sad'. For example:

- Its sad to see how fast fans *become* critics.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like 'hater' is a word often used as the opposite of 'fan'. 
So I'd go with something like this:

**It's sad to see how fast people can go form being your fans to being your haters**

Or something like that. I'm sure this sentence could sound better if you gave it a bit of tweaking.